# Translating pseudocode into C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am having a hard time with translating this pseudocode into C++. The goal is to generate random numbers into A[] and sort them using insertion sort then get the execution time in milliseconds. Insertion sort would run for m=5 times. Each n value should be 100, 200, 300,....,1000. So for example if n=100 then that would run 5 times with 5 different sets of random numbers, then do the same thing for n=200, etc...

I have already written my insertion sort and that works so I did not include it. I am really just having trouble translating this pseudocode into something I can work with. I included my attempt and the pseudocode so you can compare.

Pseudocode:

```
main()
//generate elements using rand()
for i=1 to 5
   for j=1 to 1000
      A[i,j] = rand()

//insertion sort
for (i=1; i<=5; i=i+1)
   for (n=100; n<=1000; n=n+100)
      B[1..n] = A[i,n]
      t1 = time()
      insertionSort(B,n)
      t2 = time()
      t_insort[i,n] = t2-t1

 //compute the avg time
 for (n=100; n<=1000; n=n+100)
    avgt_insort[n] = (t_insort[1,n]+t_insort[2,n]+t_insort[3,n]+...+t_insort[5,n]+)/5
 //plot graph with avgt_insort
```

This is my attempt:

I am confused with t_insort and avgt_insort, I did not write them to C++. Do I make these into new arrays? Also take I am not sure if I am doing my time correctly either. I am sorta new at this running time thing so I have never actually wrote it into code yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{   
int A[100];
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=1000; j++)
    {
        A[i,j] = rand();
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<=5; i++)
{
    for(int n=100; n<=1000; n=n+100)
    {
        static int *B = new int[n];
        B[n] = A[i,n];
        cout << "\nLength\t: " << n << '\n';
        long int t1 = clock();
        insertionSort(B, n);
        long int t2 = clock();

                    //t_insort 

        cout << "Insertion Sort\t: " << (t2 - t1) << " ms.\n";
    }
}
for(int n=100; n<=1000; n=n+100)
{
    //avt_insort[n]
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudocode is relatively close to a C++ code with some syntactic changes. Note that this C++ code is a straightforward "translation". A better solution would be to use containers from C++ standard library.

```
int main()
{
  int A[6][1001], B[1001]; //C++ starts indexing from 0
  double t_insort[6][1000]; //should be of return type of time(), so maybe not double
  int i,j,n;
for( i=1;i<=5;i++)     //in C++ it is more common to start from 0 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   for(j=1;j<=1000;j++)
      A[i][j] = rand();  //one has to include appropriate header file with rand()
                         //or to define his/her own function
for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
  for (n=100; n<=1000; n=n+100)
  {
    B[n]=A[i][n];
    t1 = time(); //one has firstly to declare t1 to be return type of time() function
    insertionSort(B,n); //also this function has to be defined before
    t2=time();
    t_insort[i][n]=t2-t1; //this may be necessary to change depending on exact return type of time()
  }
}

for (n=100; n<=1000; n=n+100)
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    avgt_insort[n] += t_insort[i][n]

avgt_insort[n]/=5;
 //plot graph with avgt_insort
```

Comment: So i have to define time() as a function? Why wouldn't clock() work?

Comment: You don't need to define your own function, clock or something else can work as well, but firstly you need to include appropriate header file with declaration of the functions.

Comment: I just made this into a (almost) working program now. I am getting an error. It is telling me that stack around the variable 'B' was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

`A[i,j]` is the same as `A[j]` (comma operator!), and wouldn't work.

You might want to declare a two dimensional array for `A` or even better an appropriate `std::array`:

```
int A[100][1000];

std::array<std::array<int,1000>, 100> A; // <- prefer this for c++
```

Also allocating `B` right away inside the for loop doesn't look right:

```
static int *B = new int[n];
```

and

```
B[n] = A[i,n];
```

won't work either as you intend (see above!).